# how to scroll using Up & Down arrow keys in Bootstrap NgbTypeahead

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using Bootstrap NgbTypeahead.(https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples)

Using key arrows, I can navigate to next item and I added a scroll to that list using css.

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I could not scroll up/down using arrow keys but the focus is going onto the item.I want to scroll the list when i hit Up/Down keys.

Is there any way to help me with this?

Comment: Where is the dropdown menu located?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574449/ngbtypeahead-component-doesnt-scroll-inside-a-scrollable-component

Comment: Nope @MukeshKumar. It was to scroll inside scrollable element. But here i want to scroll down/up using my keyboard.