# Add scrollbar to ngbTypeahead

Tags: scrollbar, typeahead

ngbTypeahead does not offer scrollbar.
I use this as the recommendation from [NgbTypeahead component doesn't scroll inside a scrollable component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574449/ngbtypeahead-component-doesnt-scroll-inside-a-scrollable-component/56174233#56174233):

```
            <div style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; position:relative">
                <input type="text" name="origin" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="origin" [(ngModel)]="data.origin" [editable]="false" [ngbTypeahead]="searchOrigin"
                    [resultFormatter]="formatDropdown" [inputFormatter]="formatSelected" placeholder="Search..."/>
            </div>
```

It works well except that it shows the ugly empty space when the list is not shown (or it does not have focus)

[image]

[image]

How to remove the empty space and the overlay pops over the other element when the list with a scroll bar appears?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have already answer this question. Please look in to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63010957/13968446

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by moving the "height" style up:

```
[style.height]="data.origin? '5rem': dropdownHeight":
```

as I see, for ngbTypeahead, when user has not selected any item, data.origin is undefined, so I want that when user has selected some item from the dropdown list, I set the height to minimum.

in .html file:

```
        <div class="form-group row" [class.has-danger]="searchFailedOrigin" [style.height]="data.origin? '5rem': dropdownHeight">

            <label for="origin" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Origin</label>

            <div class="col-sm-7 col-offset-sm-1" style="overflow-y: auto; position:relative">

                <input type="text" name="origin" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="origin" [(ngModel)]="data.origin" [editable]="false" [ngbTypeahead]="searchOrigin"
                    [resultFormatter]="formatDropdown" [inputFormatter]="formatSelected" placeholder="Search..."/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailedOrigin">No Airports Found...</div>

        </div>
```

Where dropdownHeight is updated in component .ts file in searchOrigin function:

```
searchOrigin = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    .
    .
    .

    // response is the response from server. It is a list of data filtering by "text"

    this.dropdownHeight = response.data.length <= 1? `5rem`: response.data.length <= 10? `${(response.data.length + 1) * 2.56}rem`: `28rem`;

    // An item in the dropdown list is 2.56rem in height
    // I want the maximum height is 28rem.
    .
    .
    .

}
```

This solution can remove the ugly empty space when not showing the dropdown list, but the dropdown list does not overlay the other elements.

I appreciate any improvement.